# 'flutter pub get' and 'flutter pub upgrade' not working after upgrading Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The flutter pub get and flutter pub upgrade seems not to work on my machine.

'flutter pub get' shows this error...
[image: pub get error]

and 'flutter pub upgrade' shows this...
[image: pub upgrade error]

Please, what am I doing wrong. I upgraded to Flutter v3.7.6 and Dart v2.19.3, that's when these errors began.

My 'flutter doctor -v' looks like this...

[image: flutter doctor]

Below is my pubspec.yaml file...

```
name: untitled1
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  lottie: ^2.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.18
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/newlogolight.jpg
  color: "ffffff"

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
     - assets/
```

Comment: Post your pubspec.yaml file. Also output of flutter doctor -v

Comment: @GrahamD I have made the edit. Please help me.

Comment: Looks ok. Is your network connection good and what machine are you running on?

Comment: I have solved the problem. It's a network issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thought it might be...hence the semaphore error.

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting the `Environment Variable` for `Cache`.

Go to

> C:\Users\alius\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin

`copy` this path and `add` it to the Edit environment variable

[image]

[image]

Comment: It still gives the same errors. I am confused, what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

since you still able to execute `flutter doctor`, its probably issue in your cache.
i was faced same issue before, after upgrade flutter 3.7, i cant `flutter pub get` and `flutter doctor`.

#### for Windows and macOS

you may try some steps what I've tried:

1. clear build directory

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`

if the issue still exist, continue next step.

---

2. Try to restart all your terminal and also your IDE, you may try to restart your device :D. and execute steps 1 again.

or you may try repair. but make sure your connection is fast enough.

- `flutter pub cache repair`

if the issue still exist, continue next step.

---

3. Use stable version of flutter

- `flutter channel stable`
- `flutter upgrade`

In this case, My laptop with Windows OS is fixed. But in my Mac issue still exist.

---

4. I read some source to try delete cache folder. (in my case is not solved, but some people solved the issue. So you may try this steps)

- delete cache directory `..\Pub\Cache\`
- run `flutter pub get`

if not fix, continue next step

---

5. For my last step, I just re-install my flutter in my Mac.

- Delete flutter directory
- Download flutter SDK : https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk
- I use Mackbook Pro M2 with chip Apple Silicon. Then currently update we have to accept agreement : https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#system-requirements

```
sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

- Extract the file in the desired location
- Add the flutter tool to your path. See example here : https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#get-sdk

and finally i can run `flutter doctor` on my mac. and also `flutter pub get`.

Windows and macOS done upgraded with flutter 3.7 stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command you want and look at the terminal to what you have to do, mine is saying to add the path to

```
C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
```

in **Environment Variable**.

Comment: The questioner has already provided the screenshot of his issue after running the command. Please either edit/update your answer or delete it.Thanks.