# I am trying to make a simple application but I keep getting this Error1

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, url-launcher

Because url_launcher_example depends on integration_test from path which doesn't exist (could not find package integration_test at "......\integration_test"), version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 66

exit code 66

I tried updating pub and outdating also I tried updating gradel but nothing seems to work.

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1.  Upgrade Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/upgrading.  2. Go to a new, empty directory. 3. Start VSCode and create a new project in the new directory: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=vscode, 4. Copy your app into the project, 5) Try building again.

Comment: see this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75680451/12838877

Answer (score -1):

please check if you have proper dependecies

```
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

try deleting `pubspec.lock`

then `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

also check this git page for further information on integration test  [Integration_test](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test)

Comment: If the project doesn't have much custom code, then the OP's best bet is probably to start from scratch with a "clean" project.  It's also wise to periodically run `flutter doctor`, and do a `flutter update` as required.